# Hyperbolic function and inequality

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Let's define $\sinh(x) = \frac12 (e^x-e^{-x}).$ Show that for all $x \geqslant 0$
>
> $$\sinh(x) - \sin(x) \geqslant 0.$$

How do we go about this? I'm not very comfortable with hyperbolic functions, but my initial thought was to use the derivative to show that the gradient is positive, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: power series${}$?

Comment: This was asked on a course where we haven't covered series yet, so i assume that it has something to do with the derivative.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Given $f(x) = \sinh(x) - \sin(x)$, one has that $f(0) = 0$. On the other hand, we have that
\begin{align*}
f'(x)= \cosh(x) - \cos(x) = \frac{e^{x} + e^{-x}}{2} - \cos(x)
\end{align*}
Since $-\cos(x) \geq -1$ and $\cosh(x) \geq 1$ when $x\geq 0$, we conclude that $f'(x) \geq 0$ for $x\geq 0$.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: compare both functions with $f(x)=x$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

It is equivalent to $\sinh x\ge\sin x$  for all $x\ge 0$ and is a consequence of the following corollary of the *Mean  Value theorem*:

> *Let $f, g$ be continuous functions defined on an interval $[a,b]$, differentiable in $(a,b)$.*
>
> *If $f(a)\ge g(a)$ and $f'(x)>g'(x)$ in $(a,b)$, then $f(x)\ge g(x)\:$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.*

Now observe that $\sinh 0=\sin 0=0$ and $\sinh'x> 1 $ (for all $x\ne 0)$, whereas $\sin' x=\cos x  \le 1$.